# How to broadcast video to Vimeo stably by using ffmpeg?

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, rtmp, vimeo

I'm trying to broadcast video to **Vimeo** by using `ffmpeg` to broadcast from headless linux. Seemingly I can broadcast and video has no problem, but when I see analyzer, receiving bitrate is not stable.

Nonetheless, `ffmpeg` always report stable bitrate.

```
ffmpeg version 5.0-essentials_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 11.2.0 (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-sdl2 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libgme --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-librubberband
  libavutil      57. 17.100 / 57. 17.100
  libavcodec     59. 18.100 / 59. 18.100
  libavformat    59. 16.100 / 59. 16.100
  libavdevice    59.  4.100 / 59.  4.100
  libavfilter     8. 24.100 /  8. 24.100
  libswscale      6.  4.100 /  6.  4.100
  libswresample   4.  3.100 /  4.  3.100
  libpostproc    56.  3.100 / 56.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'movie.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : dash
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: dashmp42iso6
  Duration: 00:06:00.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 5278 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080, 80 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 16k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 4 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Output #0, flv, to 'rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/0y52-fczy-u0q4-ektt-a0pu':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : dash
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: dashmp42iso6
    encoder         : Lavf59.16.100
  Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) ([7][0][0][0] / 0x0007), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080, q=2-31, 80 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) ([10][0][0][0] / 0x000A), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 4 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=  329 fps= 30 q=-1.0 size=    6644kB time=00:00:10.86 bitrate=5008.3kbits/s speed=   1x
```

If I broadcast video from my laptop by using OBS, the analyzer shows stable connection.

Here is a command I tried. Is there some problem?

```
ffmpeg -re -i <VIDEO_FILE> -codec copy -threads 4 -f flv <STREAMING_URL>/<STREAMING_KEY>
```

Comment: Streamers typically like constant bitrate. Your command is copying the video so it will be CBR only if the source stream is CBR. OBS is re-encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Gyan's comment

> Streamers typically like constant bitrate. Your command is copying the video so it will be CBR only if the source stream is CBR. OBS is re-encoding.

I found the problem is on source video side. So I determined to encode source video CBR manually every time. In my use case, it's not a bother.